# Finding a particular string in a file and copying it to a new file

Tags: batch-file

each day i will recieve a file at this location:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\LogTest\GetFile\
```

I have to search the string containing "error" in that file and copy all those error messages found in that file to another file (say result.txt) in that location. that's what all i want.  I tried like this-  Using the below command the file is created and batch commands keep running but no output in my result.txt.

(Note: I tried my best to format the code to make it readable, but there is a good part of guessing, as the original has no format at all (not even linefeeds)[Stephan])

```
echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\LogTest\GetFile\btilog.txt) do ( 
  echo %%A\%folder%
  grep "ERROR" -a5 -b2 %path2% >> Result_%file1%.txt
  if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo Values Found! logged files into Result_%file2%.txt
  ) else (
    echo No matches found in Result_%file2%.txt
  )
  pause
)
```

The sample of the log file which I have to capture:In the above code I just took 2 lines before and 5 lines after just for testing.but i want messages containing error only.

(Note: not sure, how this should look like, as there was no formating in the original [Stephan]):

```
><ns3:Error.Code>RBR.GEN.GEN.NOTOK</ns3:Error.Code><ns3:Severity.Code>Information</ns3:Severity.Code><
```

**@user3259712: please correct where I guessed wrong.** Maybe you should also explain, where %folder%, %path2% , %file1% and %file2% come from.

Answer (score 1):

For searching in files, Windows has [Findstr](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) command. Then you can save the result in a file, using [redirect operators](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true).

Also, you may find useful [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/300815/command-prompt-windows-7-grep-equivalent).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this  :   echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\l055094\Desktop\LogTest\GetFile\btilog.txt) do (
echo %%A\%folder%
grep "ERROR" -a5 -b2 %path2% >> Result_%file1%.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
                echo Values Found! logged files into Result_%file2%.txt
                ) else (
                echo No matches found in Result_%file2%.txt
                )
pause
)  but couldnt able to see the error messages in the Result.txt. I searched the batchcodes and made it this way.let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: I'm a little confused. "grep" is a linux command, it does not work in windows environment. You should use "findstr" under windows.
It seems you are mixing up commands from different OSs.
If you read the linked post, you should be able to see the correct syntax for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Is your only problem to get the output to a file?

```
find "] ERROR" Test1*.log >errors.txt
```

use `>` to create (or overwrite) to a file, use `>>` to append (or create if not existent) to a file.

Comment: I tried this but not desired output                                    echo off for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\l055094\Desktop\LogTest\GetFile\btilog.txt) do ( echo %%A\%folder% grep "ERROR" -a5 -b2 %path2% >> Result_%file1%.txt if %errorlevel%==0 ( echo Values Found! logged files into Result_%file2%.txt ) else ( echo No matches found in Result_%file2%.txt ) pause )

Comment: This seems to have nothing in common with your question. Can you please edit your question to clarify your problem?

Comment: each day i will recieve a file at this location C:\Users\l055094\Desktop\LogTest\GetFile\. I have to search the string containing "error" in that file and copy all those error messages found in that file to another file(say result.txt) in that location. that's what all i want. let me know if any confusion.

Comment: That's exactly, what my code does. (adapt filenames to your needs). How does it's output differ to your "desired output"? Maybe you should give us a few typical lines of your file and what you want to be in the output. (please edit your question, do not post this in a comment)